# Quando é uma caixa de texto funciona, porem quando é para localizar não -python -pyautogui -time

Tags: python, pyautogui

Estou fazendo um código que funciona basicamente assim:

Ele aperta em uma lista e aperta algumas iniciais para identificar com maior facilidade o item.
Porêm o pyautogui ele simula uma tecla certo?

Então por que quando eu clico com o teclado físico ele identifica os itens e quando eu automatizo com o pyautogui ele NÃO FUNCIONA, sendo que ele basicamente faz a mesma coisa, poderia ser que a aplicação limita a entrada somente com o teclado físico?

```
# Apertar nos três risquinhos
pyg.moveTo(95, 59, duration=1)
time.sleep(1)
pyg.click()

# Apertar em Configurações
pyg.moveTo(180, 208,duration=0.5)
time.sleep(1)
pyg.click()
time.sleep(2)

# Clica em selecionar servidor 
pyg.moveTo(845, 605,duration=0.5)
time.sleep(1)
pyg.click()
time.sleep(1)

# Escolhendo o EU West
def servidorEUWest():
    pyg.hotkey("shift", "a")
    pyg.hotkey("shift", "e")
    pyg.press("enter")
    return print("OK, EU West")

# Escolhendo o US South
def servidorUSSouth():
    pyg.hotkey("shift", "a")
    pyg.hotkey("shift", "u")
    pyg.hotkey("shift", "u")
    pyg.hotkey("shift", "u")
    pyg.hotkey("shift", "u")
    pyg.hotkey("shift", "u")
    pyg.hotkey("shift", "u")
    pyg.hotkey("shift", "u")
    pyg.hotkey("shift", "u")
    pyg.hotkey("shift", "u")
    pyg.press("enter")
    return print("OK, US South")

#  Ativando as funções certas
if True == certo:
    servidorUSSouth()

if False == certo:
    servidorEUWest()
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Em que lugar declarou a variável `certo`?

Answer (score -2):

Obrigado pela resposta, gostaria de comentar como resolvi meu problema para que se mais um tiver o problema, ele possa resolver com mais rapidez.

Usei o teclado virtual (natural do windows) para escrever, porém tive que fazer alguns ajustes, precisei adicionar uma tecla para ativar o teclado virtual, no meu caso foi o f2 (isso você faz nas configurações do teclado virtual) e então foi só programar a duração entre o f2, aí foi mais tentativa e erro, depois tive outro problema que não consegui fechar o teclado virtual (não entendi direito o motivo disso, mas deve ser por ser um aplicativo nativo do windows), aí para resolver isso eu precisei colocar para o pyautogui clicar com o botão direito na barra de tarefas onde iria ficar o teclado virtual, e apertar em fechar aplicativo.

E foi isso que consegui com meus testes

Espero ter ajudado se alguém tiver o mesmo problema

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Já tive casos que o sistema em que automatizei com pyautogui só aceitava a automação do python até um ponto, não continuava o processo, apenas teclando manualmente.

Agora, possa ser que seja o tempo entre um click ou outro, para isso, estabeleça bem os clicks e tempos entre eles, possa ser que rode! Aumente seu "time.sleep()" ou "duration=0.5", caso o erro persista, pode ser que você só prossiga manualmente, alguns servidores detectam isso como "malware" mesmo não sendo muitas vezes.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigado, no começo do codigo coloquei um "pyautogui.PAUSE = 1" para dar um tempo de 1 segundo entre comandos do pyautogui, mesmo não conseguindo resolver obrigado pela resposta.